# Change the permissions on a Google Doc in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-api

I can create a Google Doc, but whenever I try to access the link I get a permission denied notice. Is there a way to make the document public to anyone who has a link with the ruby client api?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert shows how to add new permissions to a document using Ruby.

To make the documents available to everyone, you have to set the permission `type` to `anyone`.